# What syntax references Pipeline parameters in the where clause of a SQL query of 'Import Data' modules in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning designer?

Tags: azure, sqlite, azure-machine-learning-service, parameterization

I have created a pipeline in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning designer.  I have added a Pipeline parameter `myNumber` in the pipeline settings, with a valid default value, to accept the unique ID of the asset in our DB so that the pipeline can return only the asset-specific data for use as our model input.  Specifically I want to reference that pipeline parameter in the where clause of the SQL query in the  'Import Data' module that connects to our Azure SQL server.

I cannot find a reference in the documentation on how to do this.  I have tried the methods specified for accomplishing this task in Azure Data Factory, using  `where RowId = @pipeline().parameters.myNumber` or `where RowId = @{variables('myNumber')}` but the experiment fails with SqlException error code '137', variable not defined.

Can you please tell me the necessary syntax to reference Pipeline parameters in the where clause of a SQL query of 'Import Data' modules of Microsoft Azure Machine Learning designer?

Answer (score 0):

The following documents may be helpful to you.

- [**Create Azure Machine Learning pipelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-machine-learning-pipelines)
- [**Transform data in Azure Machine Learning designer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-designer-transform-data)
- [**Import data into Azure Machine Learning designer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-designer-import-data)